# How do I fix booting process in Ubuntu 12.04 after the windows7 removed?

Tags: boot

The windows7 OS successfully removed, but can't boot in Ubuntu, said the bootmgr is missing. Also the hdd password is frozen.

Answer (score 1):

The boot manager for Ubuntu, GRUB2, was probably broken when you removed windows. Try using [Boot Repair](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) to fix it. First boot to the Ubuntu live CD. Open a terminal window and run the following code to install and run boot repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Then follow the instructions and options in the program to repair your boot.

You can visit http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ for more information.

Comment: @guntbert I added some information.

Answer (score 1):

Try Boot-Repair.

Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

You can either install Boot-Repair, or download it, and boot from the CD.

To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

<sup>Source:[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I already downloaded the Boot Repair disc, but it's not live. My ISO burner gone with the windows7. Do I need a live disc?

Comment: Well since you can't boot Ubuntu, you do need a bootable CD.

Comment: You should boot with Ubuntu installation media (DVD or USB). After that, you should run Boot-repair within the live OS. Not from the Boot Repair Disk.